# xml elements loading on embed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This might be a stupid question but for some reason in my swf app, the images that are supposed to load from xml just aren't when embedded, but when the .swf is visited from it's url, it works fine.

In other words when i visit

localhost/project/swf/myswf.swf < loads xml fine

But if it's embedded like

```
<embed src="/project/swf/myswf.swf"></embed>
```

That loads the swf, but none of the images load from xml in it.

At first I thought it had to do with the url being loaded in actionscript. The file structure of the swf folder would be like:

```
/swf
/elements
 - images
 - images
 - images, etc.
elements.xml
myswf.swf
```

so the swf is loading images from the elements folder after reading their url in the xml.

I changed the AS for the xml url to just "elements.xml" to the full url, and it didn't help, what could cause the problem?

Comment: because when you are loading the swf via HTML, the home directory for the swf is the HTML directory where it was loaded from, but not the directory where swf file actually lies. so the paths to images need to be updated.

Comment: Oh snap! Such an obvious solution, thanks.